# How can I put a symbol inside a glossary description

Tags: symbols, glossaries

I have to make a glossary for a work assignment, and I have ran into some trouble with the description key. I have looked all over google and cannot seem to find an answer for how to put a symbol inside the description key of the glossary term. Basically I have to make definitions that have `alpha`s and `mu`s etc inside the definition itself.

My example is:

```
%% glossary.tex %%

\documentclass{exam}

%%% Set Up Glossary Options in Global Preamble %%%
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\makenoidxglossaries
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Load Glossary from external file
\loadglsentries{entries.tex}

\begin{document}

  % Option to print all terms in glossary even when they are unused
  \glsaddall

  % Actually print the glossary
  \printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

The actual glossary is here:

```
%% entries.tex %%

%%% Glossary Entries

\newglossaryentry{hello}{
  name = hello,
  description = {The mean is mu},
  sort = hello
}
```

I would like the 'mu' to be replaced with the greek letter mu. Being somewhat new to LaTex, any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use logical markup with a command `\meansymbol`, which is set to `\mu` here, which prints the usual italic version of the greek letter mu. This way, it's easy to make a consistent notation throughout the document.

Additionally, I provided the upshape version, `\upmu` in the `\meanupsymbol` -- this requires `\usepackage{upgreek}` then. (Of course, `\upmu` can be used in `\meansymbol` too ;-)

Both versions require the switch to math mode, i.e. `$\mu$` or `$\upmu$`

The `alpha` letter would be `\alpha` then, `beta` is achieved with `\beta` etc.

```
\documentclass{exam}

%%% Set Up Glossary Options in Global Preamble %%%
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\makenoidxglossaries

\newcommand{\meansymbol}{\mu}
\newcommand{\meanupsymbol}{\upmu}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Load Glossary from external file
\loadglsentries{entries.tex}

\begin{document}

  % Option to print all terms in glossary even when they are unused
  \glsaddall

  % Actually print the glossary
  \printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

The `entries.tex` contains

```
\newglossaryentry{hello}{
  name = hello,
  description = {The mean is $\meansymbol$},
  sort = hello
}

\newglossaryentry{uphello}{
  name = uphello,
  description = {The upshape version of mean is $\meanupsymbol$},
  sort = uphello
}
```

[image]